# Jquery: Convert any CSS color to rgb

Tags: jquery, rgb

Is there a quick way I can covert any css color such as `#ffe`, `whitesmoke`, or `hsl(20,50%,80%)`, to a rgb color like `rgb(140,75,20)`?

Can I use the `.css()` method on a variable to convert the color to rgb somehow?

Comment: Check this answer for RGB to hex conversion: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5624139/1606729

Answer (score -1):

This may answer your question - 
[RGB to Hex and Hex to RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb)

```
function hexToRgb(hex) {
   var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
   return result ? {
       r: parseInt(result[1], 16),
       g: parseInt(result[2], 16),
       b: parseInt(result[3], 16)
   } : null;
}

alert( hexToRgb("#0033ff").g ); // "51";
```

Comment: Thanks! however I'm looking for a way to convert _any_ CSS color, not just hex.. This is a step in the right direction though.

Comment: I've not seen an all-in-one before, so you may need to do some digging. Here's what I came across for HSL - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804027/farbtastic-convert-hsl-back-to-rgb-or-hex.