# PHP / imagecolorat : transform colors in RGB but missing colors

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a script producing histograms from JPG, PNGs,...
I can get all the colors pixels by pixels with imagecolorat but if I want to display them in CSS, I need to convert them in RGB.

I have used the following script which is available on many sites:

```
$r = ($a >> 16) & 0xFF;
$g = ($a >> 8) & 0xFF;
$b = $a & 0xFF;     
$v = round(($r + $g + $b) / 3);
```

As I wanted to display the corresponding colors under my histogram, I did the following:

```
$mapping = array();
for ($a=0;$a<=16777215;$a++)
{
    $r = ($a >> 16) & 0xFF;
    $g = ($a >> 8) & 0xFF;
    $b = $a & 0xFF;     
    $v = round(($r + $g + $b) / 3);
    
    $mapping[$v] = $r.",".$g.",".$b;    
}
```

The output of this array is the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1,0,0
    [1] => 4,0,0
    [2] => 7,0,0
    [3] => 10,0,0
    [4] => 13,0,0
    [5] => 16,0,0
    [6] => 19,0,0
    [7] => 22,0,0
    [8] => 25,0,0
    [9] => 28,0,0
    [10] => 31,0,0
    [11] => 34,0,0
    [12] => 37,0,0
    [13] => 40,0,0
    [14] => 43,0,0
    [15] => 46,0,0
    [16] => 49,0,0
    [17] => 52,0,0
    [18] => 55,0,0
    [19] => 58,0,0
    [20] => 61,0,0
    [21] => 64,0,0
    [22] => 67,0,0
    [23] => 70,0,0
    [24] => 73,0,0
    [25] => 76,0,0
    [26] => 79,0,0
    [27] => 82,0,0
    [28] => 85,0,0
    [29] => 88,0,0
    [30] => 91,0,0
    [31] => 94,0,0
    [32] => 97,0,0
    [33] => 100,0,0
    [34] => 103,0,0
    [35] => 106,0,0
    [36] => 109,0,0
    [37] => 112,0,0
    [38] => 115,0,0
    [39] => 118,0,0
    [40] => 121,0,0
    [41] => 124,0,0
    [42] => 127,0,0
    [43] => 130,0,0
    [44] => 133,0,0
    [45] => 136,0,0
    [46] => 139,0,0
    [47] => 142,0,0
    [48] => 145,0,0
    [49] => 148,0,0
    [50] => 151,0,0
    [51] => 154,0,0
    [52] => 157,0,0
    [53] => 160,0,0
    [54] => 163,0,0
    [55] => 166,0,0
    [56] => 169,0,0
    [57] => 172,0,0
    [58] => 175,0,0
    [59] => 178,0,0
    [60] => 181,0,0
    [61] => 184,0,0
    [62] => 187,0,0
    [63] => 190,0,0
    [64] => 193,0,0
    [65] => 196,0,0
    [66] => 199,0,0
    [67] => 202,0,0
    [68] => 205,0,0
    [69] => 208,0,0
    [70] => 211,0,0
    [71] => 214,0,0
    [72] => 217,0,0
    [73] => 220,0,0
    [74] => 223,0,0
    [75] => 226,0,0
    [76] => 229,0,0
    [77] => 232,0,0
    [78] => 235,0,0
    [79] => 238,0,0
    [80] => 241,0,0
    [81] => 244,0,0
    [82] => 247,0,0
    [83] => 250,0,0
    [84] => 253,0,0
    [85] => 255,1,0
    [86] => 255,4,0
    [87] => 255,7,0
    [88] => 255,10,0
    [89] => 255,13,0
    [90] => 255,16,0
    [91] => 255,19,0
    [92] => 255,22,0
    [93] => 255,25,0
    [94] => 255,28,0
    [95] => 255,31,0
    [96] => 255,34,0
    [97] => 255,37,0
    [98] => 255,40,0
    [99] => 255,43,0
    [100] => 255,46,0
    [101] => 255,49,0
    [102] => 255,52,0
    [103] => 255,55,0
    [104] => 255,58,0
    [105] => 255,61,0
    [106] => 255,64,0
    [107] => 255,67,0
    [108] => 255,70,0
    [109] => 255,73,0
    [110] => 255,76,0
    [111] => 255,79,0
    [112] => 255,82,0
    [113] => 255,85,0
    [114] => 255,88,0
    [115] => 255,91,0
    [116] => 255,94,0
    [117] => 255,97,0
    [118] => 255,100,0
    [119] => 255,103,0
    [120] => 255,106,0
    [121] => 255,109,0
    [122] => 255,112,0
    [123] => 255,115,0
    [124] => 255,118,0
    [125] => 255,121,0
    [126] => 255,124,0
    [127] => 255,127,0
    [128] => 255,130,0
    [129] => 255,133,0
    [130] => 255,136,0
    [131] => 255,139,0
    [132] => 255,142,0
    [133] => 255,145,0
    [134] => 255,148,0
    [135] => 255,151,0
    [136] => 255,154,0
    [137] => 255,157,0
    [138] => 255,160,0
    [139] => 255,163,0
    [140] => 255,166,0
    [141] => 255,169,0
    [142] => 255,172,0
    [143] => 255,175,0
    [144] => 255,178,0
    [145] => 255,181,0
    [146] => 255,184,0
    [147] => 255,187,0
    [148] => 255,190,0
    [149] => 255,193,0
    [150] => 255,196,0
    [151] => 255,199,0
    [152] => 255,202,0
    [153] => 255,205,0
    [154] => 255,208,0
    [155] => 255,211,0
    [156] => 255,214,0
    [157] => 255,217,0
    [158] => 255,220,0
    [159] => 255,223,0
    [160] => 255,226,0
    [161] => 255,229,0
    [162] => 255,232,0
    [163] => 255,235,0
    [164] => 255,238,0
    [165] => 255,241,0
    [166] => 255,244,0
    [167] => 255,247,0
    [168] => 255,250,0
    [169] => 255,253,0
    [170] => 255,255,1
    [171] => 255,255,4
    [172] => 255,255,7
    [173] => 255,255,10
    [174] => 255,255,13
    [175] => 255,255,16
    [176] => 255,255,19
    [177] => 255,255,22
    [178] => 255,255,25
    [179] => 255,255,28
    [180] => 255,255,31
    [181] => 255,255,34
    [182] => 255,255,37
    [183] => 255,255,40
    [184] => 255,255,43
    [185] => 255,255,46
    [186] => 255,255,49
    [187] => 255,255,52
    [188] => 255,255,55
    [189] => 255,255,58
    [190] => 255,255,61
    [191] => 255,255,64
    [192] => 255,255,67
    [193] => 255,255,70
    [194] => 255,255,73
    [195] => 255,255,76
    [196] => 255,255,79
    [197] => 255,255,82
    [198] => 255,255,85
    [199] => 255,255,88
    [200] => 255,255,91
    [201] => 255,255,94
    [202] => 255,255,97
    [203] => 255,255,100
    [204] => 255,255,103
    [205] => 255,255,106
    [206] => 255,255,109
    [207] => 255,255,112
    [208] => 255,255,115
    [209] => 255,255,118
    [210] => 255,255,121
    [211] => 255,255,124
    [212] => 255,255,127
    [213] => 255,255,130
    [214] => 255,255,133
    [215] => 255,255,136
    [216] => 255,255,139
    [217] => 255,255,142
    [218] => 255,255,145
    [219] => 255,255,148
    [220] => 255,255,151
    [221] => 255,255,154
    [222] => 255,255,157
    [223] => 255,255,160
    [224] => 255,255,163
    [225] => 255,255,166
    [226] => 255,255,169
    [227] => 255,255,172
    [228] => 255,255,175
    [229] => 255,255,178
    [230] => 255,255,181
    [231] => 255,255,184
    [232] => 255,255,187
    [233] => 255,255,190
    [234] => 255,255,193
    [235] => 255,255,196
    [236] => 255,255,199
    [237] => 255,255,202
    [238] => 255,255,205
    [239] => 255,255,208
    [240] => 255,255,211
    [241] => 255,255,214
    [242] => 255,255,217
    [243] => 255,255,220
    [244] => 255,255,223
    [245] => 255,255,226
    [246] => 255,255,229
    [247] => 255,255,232
    [248] => 255,255,235
    [249] => 255,255,238
    [250] => 255,255,241
    [251] => 255,255,244
    [252] => 255,255,247
    [253] => 255,255,250
    [254] => 255,255,253
    [255] => 255,255,255
)
```

As you can see, there is already something wrong visible here because a whole bunch of colors are missing.

If I display those colors, I get this:
[image]

I started with the assumption that the max value for imagecolorat was 16777215. I got that value by asking the color index of a white pixel. Was I wrong?

Do you know how I could have a more accurate array of colors for my histogram?

Thanks

Blues and greens are completely missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a loop for the 3 colors (red, green, blue) to get more distinct colors.

In the following example, you will get the black, red, green, blue, white (and many others).

Code: ([demo](https://3v4l.org/IFDvv))

```
$ndiv = 5; // small => less colors ; big => more colors
$div = 255 / $ndiv;

$mapping = [];
for ($r = 0; $r <= 255; $r += $div) {
  for ($g = 0; $g <= 255; $g += $div) {
    for ($b = 0; $b <= 255; $b += $div) {
      $mapping[] = sprintf("%d,%d,%d", $r, $g, $b);    
    }
  }
}

print_r($mapping);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0,0,0
    [1] => 0,0,51
    [2] => 0,0,102
    [3] => 0,0,153
    [4] => 0,0,204
    [5] => 0,0,255
    [6] => 0,51,0
    [7] => 0,51,51
    [8] => 0,51,102
    [9] => 0,51,153
    [10] => 0,51,204
    [11] => 0,51,255
    [12] => 0,102,0
    [13] => 0,102,51
    [14] => 0,102,102
    [15] => 0,102,153
    [16] => 0,102,204
    [17] => 0,102,255
    [18] => 0,153,0
    [19] => 0,153,51
    [20] => 0,153,102
    [21] => 0,153,153
    [22] => 0,153,204
    [23] => 0,153,255
    [24] => 0,204,0
    [25] => 0,204,51
    [26] => 0,204,102
    [27] => 0,204,153
    [28] => 0,204,204
    [29] => 0,204,255
    [30] => 0,255,0
    [31] => 0,255,51
    [32] => 0,255,102
    [33] => 0,255,153
    [34] => 0,255,204
    [35] => 0,255,255
    [36] => 51,0,0
    [37] => 51,0,51
    [38] => 51,0,102
    [39] => 51,0,153
    [40] => 51,0,204
    [41] => 51,0,255
    [42] => 51,51,0
    [43] => 51,51,51
    [44] => 51,51,102
    [45] => 51,51,153
    [46] => 51,51,204
    [47] => 51,51,255
    [48] => 51,102,0
    [49] => 51,102,51
    [50] => 51,102,102
    [51] => 51,102,153
    [52] => 51,102,204
    [53] => 51,102,255
    [54] => 51,153,0
    [55] => 51,153,51
    [56] => 51,153,102
    [57] => 51,153,153
    [58] => 51,153,204
    [59] => 51,153,255
    [60] => 51,204,0
    [61] => 51,204,51
    [62] => 51,204,102
    [63] => 51,204,153
    [64] => 51,204,204
    [65] => 51,204,255
    [66] => 51,255,0
    [67] => 51,255,51
    [68] => 51,255,102
    [69] => 51,255,153
    [70] => 51,255,204
    [71] => 51,255,255
    [72] => 102,0,0
    [73] => 102,0,51
    [74] => 102,0,102
    [75] => 102,0,153
    [76] => 102,0,204
    [77] => 102,0,255
    [78] => 102,51,0
    [79] => 102,51,51
    [80] => 102,51,102
    [81] => 102,51,153
    [82] => 102,51,204
    [83] => 102,51,255
    [84] => 102,102,0
    [85] => 102,102,51
    [86] => 102,102,102
    [87] => 102,102,153
    [88] => 102,102,204
    [89] => 102,102,255
    [90] => 102,153,0
    [91] => 102,153,51
    [92] => 102,153,102
    [93] => 102,153,153
    [94] => 102,153,204
    [95] => 102,153,255
    [96] => 102,204,0
    [97] => 102,204,51
    [98] => 102,204,102
    [99] => 102,204,153
    [100] => 102,204,204
    [101] => 102,204,255
    [102] => 102,255,0
    [103] => 102,255,51
    [104] => 102,255,102
    [105] => 102,255,153
    [106] => 102,255,204
    [107] => 102,255,255
    [108] => 153,0,0
    [109] => 153,0,51
    [110] => 153,0,102
    [111] => 153,0,153
    [112] => 153,0,204
    [113] => 153,0,255
    [114] => 153,51,0
    [115] => 153,51,51
    [116] => 153,51,102
    [117] => 153,51,153
    [118] => 153,51,204
    [119] => 153,51,255
    [120] => 153,102,0
    [121] => 153,102,51
    [122] => 153,102,102
    [123] => 153,102,153
    [124] => 153,102,204
    [125] => 153,102,255
    [126] => 153,153,0
    [127] => 153,153,51
    [128] => 153,153,102
    [129] => 153,153,153
    [130] => 153,153,204
    [131] => 153,153,255
    [132] => 153,204,0
    [133] => 153,204,51
    [134] => 153,204,102
    [135] => 153,204,153
    [136] => 153,204,204
    [137] => 153,204,255
    [138] => 153,255,0
    [139] => 153,255,51
    [140] => 153,255,102
    [141] => 153,255,153
    [142] => 153,255,204
    [143] => 153,255,255
    [144] => 204,0,0
    [145] => 204,0,51
    [146] => 204,0,102
    [147] => 204,0,153
    [148] => 204,0,204
    [149] => 204,0,255
    [150] => 204,51,0
    [151] => 204,51,51
    [152] => 204,51,102
    [153] => 204,51,153
    [154] => 204,51,204
    [155] => 204,51,255
    [156] => 204,102,0
    [157] => 204,102,51
    [158] => 204,102,102
    [159] => 204,102,153
    [160] => 204,102,204
    [161] => 204,102,255
    [162] => 204,153,0
    [163] => 204,153,51
    [164] => 204,153,102
    [165] => 204,153,153
    [166] => 204,153,204
    [167] => 204,153,255
    [168] => 204,204,0
    [169] => 204,204,51
    [170] => 204,204,102
    [171] => 204,204,153
    [172] => 204,204,204
    [173] => 204,204,255
    [174] => 204,255,0
    [175] => 204,255,51
    [176] => 204,255,102
    [177] => 204,255,153
    [178] => 204,255,204
    [179] => 204,255,255
    [180] => 255,0,0
    [181] => 255,0,51
    [182] => 255,0,102
    [183] => 255,0,153
    [184] => 255,0,204
    [185] => 255,0,255
    [186] => 255,51,0
    [187] => 255,51,51
    [188] => 255,51,102
    [189] => 255,51,153
    [190] => 255,51,204
    [191] => 255,51,255
    [192] => 255,102,0
    [193] => 255,102,51
    [194] => 255,102,102
    [195] => 255,102,153
    [196] => 255,102,204
    [197] => 255,102,255
    [198] => 255,153,0
    [199] => 255,153,51
    [200] => 255,153,102
    [201] => 255,153,153
    [202] => 255,153,204
    [203] => 255,153,255
    [204] => 255,204,0
    [205] => 255,204,51
    [206] => 255,204,102
    [207] => 255,204,153
    [208] => 255,204,204
    [209] => 255,204,255
    [210] => 255,255,0
    [211] => 255,255,51
    [212] => 255,255,102
    [213] => 255,255,153
    [214] => 255,255,204
    [215] => 255,255,255
)
```

With `$ndiv = 1`, you'll get

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0,0,0
    [1] => 0,0,255
    [2] => 0,255,0
    [3] => 0,255,255
    [4] => 255,0,0
    [5] => 255,0,255
    [6] => 255,255,0
    [7] => 255,255,255
)
```

---

To get a continuation in colors, you can use HSL (Hue, Saturation, Luminosity). By moving the hue from 0 to 360°, you will get a full color wheel.

Here is an example for CSS property:

```
for ($h=0;$h<360;$h+=2) {
    echo'<div style="background:hsl('.$h.',100%,50%);float:left;width:8px;height:12px;"></div>';
}
```

Output:

[image]

If you need a `rgb()` value, you can convert using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20440417/9193372)

Comment: Thanks! I get a better granularity so that's a good point but I need to keep the order so that I can use those colors below a histogram. Do you see a way to increment colors from black to white in the right order? If you check my code, that's why I used 0 to 16777215.

Comment: I've updated the answer to add another way to do it using HSL.

Comment: But I realize that this will not get a black to white wheel... but you could also play with luminosity as well.

Comment: This approach is better, the color coverage is more accurate but I need white & black + all grey gradients. Do you know a way to translate the color index from imagecolorat and map it to a color range like the one your proposed in your last comment? The order should follow the color index from imagecolorat as this will always be the starting point. The mapping variable is just there to provide a visual support. imagecolorat will give me colors from the picture and I'd like to display them like an histogram show the full color spectrum (a bit like what you have in Photoshop)

Comment: I have found an interesting article of someone who was trying to achieve the same and the conclusion is that it's not possible: https://www.hashbangcode.com/article/color-sorting-php

Comment: Interesting link.